# Deadlock found in MySQL (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-deadlocks

I'm getting the following error pretty often when running a certain query in my database (all tables use the InnoDB storage engine): "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"

The query is `DELETE FROM sessions WHERE userid != 0 AND lastactivity < 1289594761 AND admin = 1 AND userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM users WHERE (userflags & 1048576))`

The errors started to occur when I've added the NOT IN part to my WHERE statement.
Why is this causing issues and what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: While you might be able to minimize deadlocks, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596005/working-around-mysql-error-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restartin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be to separate this into two consecutive queries. I.e.,:

SELECT userid into #tmptable FROM users WHERE (userflags & 1048576);

DELETE FROM sessions WHERE userid != 0 AND lastactivity < 1289594761 AND admin = 1 AND userid NOT IN (select userid from #tmptable);

That way you're working with a local session copy of the values from the second table and not causing a read lock on it. However, this is just a quick-and-dirty solution. A better solution would be to analyze the transaction lock settings from all activities that touch these two tables and to rewrite the query, if you'll be re-using it regularly.

Comment: It's just used in a maintenance cronjob so if it fails from time to time it's not a big thing - I've ignored them for a few months now but having to delete the error notification mails gets annoying. ;)

Comment: Btw, I've done it similar to what you've suggested - not using a temp table but simply storing the userid list in my PHP code and then using `IN (list,of,userids)` in the DELETE statement.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you get the error more often because this is now a much slower query.

The `&` op on `userflags` makes the subquery unindexable. Flag words aren't usually good schema design, as they require computation that defeats indexing. If you are doing bit testing queries a lot, separate columns of small datatypes (eg `TINYINT`) may be better.

If your schema works the way it looks like it might, you should be able to do this using a simple JOIN, which usually performs better than a subqueries:

```
DELETE sessions
FROM sessions
JOIN users ON users.userid=sessions.userid
WHERE sessions.lastactivity<1289594761 AND admin=1
AND (users.userflags&1048576)=0
```

(joins on `DELETE` is a non-ANSI SQL extension in MySQL.)

Comment: I guess you wanted to say `AND NOT (users.userflags & 1048579)` - but nice suggestion, I didn't think about using JOINs because IMO using JOINs in a DELETE/UPDATE statement makes the query look odd