# MySQL JDBC: Is there an option for automatic retry after InnoDB deadlock?

Tags: java, mysql, innodb, deadlock

I am [Working around MySQL error “Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596005/working-around-mysql-error-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restartin)

I found out that the transaction can be safely reattempted

> Deadlocks are not dangerous. Just try again.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

There was a single "super insert..select" statement that inserted into the bottleneck table after selecting a joined combo of two other tables and using sub-statements conditions on the bottleneck table as well as a few tiny tables.

The bottle neck was "waiting for lock", it was waiting for write lock no doubt. InnoDB seemed the perfect fit. (for write-heavy table) And the hesitations on this one statement are now all gone.

But now the problem arises: For every 100 executions of the statement, about 1 or 2 of them will fail because of the deadlock. I believe the deadlock only occurs between instances of the "super insert..select". I will install an auto retry of that statement, but I wondered

**Question:** Does MySQL JDBC have an option to turn on auto-retry of statements after receiving the exception, or do I have to write my own code for that?

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

In this case, I do not have start transaction or stop transaction commands. Just that one "super insert..select" statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can repeat the statement but in a perfect world you should rollback your transaction and start it again. And your transactions would be short in that world :)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey The answer is retry the entire transaction, not just the statement.