# Spring Data JPA Deadlock Issues with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a complex business web application that receives multiple concurrent requests. One of those requests is to process a new invoice. If multiple of these requests are received at the same time, at least one of the requests will suffer a rollback because of the following error `Transaction (Process ID X) was deadlocked on lock resources`.

I have been browsing through lots of StackOverflow entries about this topic, but none of them have given me a solution. I tried turning on `SNAPSHOT ISOLATION`, but nothing changed. I have try reordering my code, but to no avail. User https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560836/user1560836 commented on [Correct way to handle deadlocks in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551005/correct-way-to-handle-deadlocks-in-hibernate) that there simply was no solution to this issue, and it seems likely. Still, I find it hard to believe, given how **used** these frameworks are.

Does anybody have a recommendation or maybe a solution? Also, do you have a solution to at least monitor these occurrences? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) With any large database deadlocks are not only possible, but sometimes unavoidable. In which case you either need a retry mechanism *OR* a serialisation mechanism.

Comment: And yes there are monitoring tools and solutions out there, your favourite search engine should assist you with that.

Comment: Query/index tuning often mitigates deadlocks by touch only data needed for the task at hand. Take a look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone who finds themselves in my same predicament, the solution that had the best results so far is `Optimistic Locking`. Following this very helpful [Baeldung guide](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking), I managed to solve my issue in a elegant way.

You can find below a summary of what I did to achieve this.

1. Added a `bigint` field to the tables that were modified in the commonly deadlocked transactions (database wise)
2. Then, added this new field with the `@Version` annotation to the JPA entities that are being modified

This simple solution solved most of my deadlocked issues.

Additionally, you can use [Spring Retry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) to retry deadlock transactions automatically, without needing to resend the request. Also, you can tell Spring to only retry deadlock related exceptions with the following annotation.

```
@Retryable(value = {CannotAcquireLockException.class, OptimisticLockException.class, TransactionException.class, ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.class})
```

Hope it helps somebody else.