# MySQL - Deadlock found when trying to get lock

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I have table `tt_users` which has `id` as primary key, and columns `state` (CHAR(1)), which can be "x" or "y", and `state_position` (INT). There are no indexes on these columns. Storage engine is innodb.

state_positions must always be consecutive, and there may never be a duplicate position for a certain state, i.e. if I have 5 users with state 'x', their state_positions must be 1,2,3,4,5

This is the query I'm running that causes deadlocks:

```
insert into `tt_users` (`state`, `state_position`) 
values ('x',
   (SELECT MAX(state_position) AS maxStatePosition
    FROM tt_users AS u2
    WHERE u2.state='x') + 1
)
```

For testing, I inserted a large amount of users simultaneously, and each time I got the deadlock error.

I read this post - [How to avoid mysql 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans) but I didn't understand what I should do with my query to prevent deadlocks, if that is at all possible, since the answer to this question - [Working around MySQL error "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596005/working-around-mysql-error-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarti) - says deadlocks can happen no matter what.

The only way I managed to get this to work, and work consistently, is this (language is PHP):

```
PDO::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

Then locking the table manually, and running my query:

```
SET autocommit=0;

LOCK TABLES
tt_users WRITE,
tt_users AS u2 WRITE;

insert into `tt_users` (`state`, `state_position`) 
values ('x',
   (SELECT MAX(state_position) AS maxStatePosition
    FROM tt_users AS u2
    WHERE u2.state='x') + 1
);

COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

And then:

```
PDO::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

With that method I ran the code 4 times simultaneously, each instance inserting 2500 users, without problems.

Is that the only way to get this to work, or can I with 100% certainty prevent deadlocks without having to manually lock the table?

**UPDATE:**

Per @wallyk's answer, I tried the following:

1) Putting the query in a transaction - still deadlock error
2) Starting the transaction with `WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT`, `READ WRITE`, `READ ONLY`. All 3 options required `PDO::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);` to be set. `WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT` and `READ WRITE` still gave me deadlock error, while `READ ONLY` naturally didn't even allow me to execute the `INSERT`.

So for now it appears manually locking the table is the only thing that works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will help, but surrounding the SQL statement with a transaction may provide the correct locking sequence internally:

```
start transaction;
insert into `tt_users` (`state`, `state_position`) 
values ('x',
   (SELECT MAX(state_position) AS maxStatePosition
    FROM tt_users AS u2
    WHERE u2.state='x') + 1
);
commit;
```

If that doesn't work, there are a few options which can be added to the `start transaction` statement.  See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try all of these and get back with results.

Comment: Updated question with results from having tried your suggestion. Sadly, it didn't work.