# How to solve below dead lock issue?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

Getting deadlock error, during `INSERT` statements:

**Key**:

```
insert into status (userid,lastactivity,lastseen) 
                 values ('10691250','1536136821','1536136821') 
      on duplicate key update lastactivity = '1536136821',
                              lastseen = '1536136821'
```

**SQL**:

```
`insert into status (userid,lastactivity,lastseen) 
                  values ('10691250','1536136821','1536136821') 
      on duplicate key 
      update lastactivity = '1536136821',
             lastseen = '1536136821'`
```

**Error**:

> Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596005/working-around-mysql-error-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarti

Comment: Thanks for reply but I already check the provided link.

Comment: Then you could've _at least_ mentioned _that_ in your question (along with all the proposed solutions in there that you, supposedly then, also tried). Your question contains no information whatsoever besides a query and an error.